# How to define minority/majority class in a multi-classification task

Tags: class-imbalance, imbalanced-data

I am studying classification in imbalanced datasets and I am learning under/over sampling strategies as a way to address the issue. While the literature agrees one needs to oversample 'minority' classes and downsample 'majority' classes, I have not been able to find a clear definition of how minority/majority is defined/measured.

While this is not much an issue in a binary classification task, my problem is a multi-classification one, where there are over 200 classes, some have tens of thousands of examples some have under a hundred. But how do you scientifically decide which are majority, which are minority?

I'd appreciate some help on this, especially if you have any references that I can ready.

Thanks

Comment: Statisticians do not see class imbalance as such a problem. There is no need to use undersampling, oversampling, or artificial balancing to solve a non-problem. It might be helpful if you say why you find the imbalance problematic. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to understand that class imbalance is not really a problem, and consequently resampling is not a very good approach (see for instance [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/90666/64377) or [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/101913/64377)). Resampling is easy to do so many tutorial for beginners insist on it, but it almost never succeeds at solving the problem because it doesn't address the real underlying issue: if a classifier assigns the majority label to many instances, it's because it doesn't know how to distinguish the classes.

So my main answer is: don't resample :)

If you really want to try resampling in the case of multiclass, there's no need to define the classes as minority or majority. Resampling is just creating an artificially balanced distribution, so this can be done in the same way with multiple classes. For example you might decide that you want 200 instances of every class, so you oversample the classes which have less than 200 and undersample the ones which have more.

Remember that resampling must only be applied to the training set.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more useful to reframe the probelm more pragmatically, compared to scientifically.

Many real-world classification problems have a long tail of categories with relatively few examples. The most common pragmatic approaches:

- Drop the instances where the category has relatively few examples
- Group categories together into a new catch-all category, aka "dustbin"
- Use domain knowledge to group categories together

The result is fewer categories with more examples in each category. There will still be categories of more or fewer examples, aka majority/minority categories. Then other approaches can be taken (e.g., resampling or class weights).